# Swift 4: Inbuilt String.hashValue generates same result for different strings

Tags: swift

While generating hash values using Swift's built in string hashValue, we found a case where two different strings generate the same hash value... but the cause of the collision is very perplexing..

Take these two strings:

```
var str1 = """
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000100000
00000000000000
00000000000
""" //Contains a single 1 character
var str2 = """
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000
""" //Contains only zeroes

str1 == str2 // false
str1.hashValue == str2.hashValue // true ..WAT?
```

- If we trim both strings by a single character, the hashValues are **different**.
- If we append **different** characters, the hashValues are **different**.
- If we append **identical** characters, the hashValues are the **same**.

Would love to understand what's going on here...

Thanks

Comment: It would seem that `hashValue` only looks at the first 75 characters of a string. But in the end it's fine. `hashValue` is not meant to be unique.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried using two strings that had identical characters for their first 75 characters. The `hashValue` wasn't the same. I was told by another dev that it uses characters from the first, middle, last portions of the string...so maybe that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at official documentation from Apple on [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol. It says:

> A hash value, provided by a type’s hashValue property, is an integer that is the same for any two instances that compare equally. That is, for two instances `a` and `b` of the same type, if `a == b`, then `a.hashValue == b.hashValue`. **The reverse is not true:** Two instances with equal hash values are not necessarily equal to each other.

You can also get more by reading this [post](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/hashable-protocols-in-swift-baf0cabeaebd)

Answer (score 2):

> **Don’t ever assume that two items with the same hash value are equal.**
>   This happens because you XOR the individual hash values but XOR’ing a
>   value with itself gives zero (A ^ A = 0).

Maybe this article would give you the answer

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-hashable/

Cheers,